# Logical Volume Not Showing on Explorer

Tags: partitioning, logical-drive

I created an extended partition and a logical volume therein using DISKPART and formatted (NTFS, quick). But the logical volume (E:) is not showing in explorer (My Computer). I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.
[image]
[image]

Is there anything wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using any external drives which are also mapped to the letter E: ?

Comment: Not sure, but that could be possible. What should be my approach, then?

Comment: Try giving it another driver letter and see if it shows up in explorer.  (XP did have that problem, but you have win7, so this is just a guess)

Comment: Tried from F: to Z:. Not working. Please help!